# Filemaker - How to add new instance of related record from parent record layout

Tags: filemaker

I am new to filemaker pro so hopefully this isn't too stupid of a question. I took a few online classes and everything makes sense except for when I want to work with related fields. I tried to find this one google but I am either searching with the wrong key words or it just ins't really out there.

Basically I want to create a new record and be able to add references to its related fields. I have messages which can have numerous speakers. These speakers are references to the message table via a message speaker xref table. I am able to display the speakers that are already in the database (I imported the data from another source that already had many values) but I am not able to add new ones from the message layout. 
I would like to just use the popup control with a multi selection. The problem I am running into is when I add a new message the popup control doesn't populate with the records from speakers.

I already tried this by adding a button to execute sql to add the reference with a default speaker but I wasn't able to get the script to execute correctly. I am not even sure if that is the best way.

Hopefully this makes sense. My rep is still to low to post images otherwise I will attach the DB connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an older post, however I wonder if your problem is solved. In FileMaker's layout mode inspector you can specify a "Values from:" parameter. When you select the field, change it's Values from: and create a new value list. Set that new value list to "Use values from first field" for speaker names. If the speaker table has a primary key field then you can instead set a foreign key value for the speaker. To get fancy you can select and display the FK field using a drop down arrow, then overlay a text field over top of the FK field to present the speaker's friendly name.

HTH.